# compiling error while declaring sfr address

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, keil, 8051

i am working on a 8051 based MCU STC16C65A and i want it to emit PWM thru P2.0, sp i copy and modify this code from their manual:

```
#include "8051.h"

    sfr AUXR = 0x8e;
                //Auxiliary register T0 interrupt service routine
void t0int() interrupt 1           //(location at 000BH)
{
}
void main()
{
    AUXR = 0x80;
                //timer0 work in 1T mode
    TMOD = 0x06;                  //set timer0 as counter mode2 (8-bit auto-reload)
    TL0 = TH0 = 0xff;               //fill with 0xff to count one time
    TR0 = 1;                        //timer0 start run
    ET0 = 1;                        //enable T0 interrupt
    EA = 1;                         //open global interrupt switch
    IF P2.0 = 0 THEN P2.0 = 1 ELSE P2.0 = 0;
    while (1);
}
```

but when i compile it using MCU 8051 ide comes out a syntax error, declaration ignored in sfr AUXR = 0x8e; i think is that the library used (8051.reg) is a generic one instead of the reg51.h (oudated) that they suggest in the manual which i dont use because cames a error message of library out to date
Who can hep me? maybe i have to choose another adress for that pointer?
thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the **exact** error message and the version of the compiler you use.

Comment: i belived that the problem was in the header file, That i have to change the adress of AUXR, but after i deleted all comments, this comes out
PWMTimer0Mode2.c:2: error 1: Syntax error, declaration ignored at 'sfr'
PWMTimer0Mode2.c:2: syntax error: token -> 'AUXR' ; column 8
PWMTimer0Mode2.c:9: error 1: Syntax error, declaration ignored at 'TMOD'
PWMTimer0Mode2.c:10: error 1: Syntax error, declaration ignored at 'TL0'
PWMTimer0Mode2.c:11: error 1: Syntax error, declaration ignored at 'TR0'
PWMTimer0Mode2.c:12: error 1: Syntax error, declaration ignored at 'ET0'
PWMTimer0Mode2.c:13: ...

Comment: i use sdcc-4.0; simply is not compiling, the question is why this error messages?

Comment: You still did not [edit] your question with the error message. Please do this. However, as SDCC is a different compiler than Keil, you have to expect differences in extensions to the C standard. And the declaration of SFRs is an extension. Please read SDCC's documentation!

Answer (score 0):

SDCC is a different compiler than Keil C51, you have to expect differences in extensions to the C standard. And the declaration of SFRs is an extension.

Please use the documented syntax:

```
__sfr __at(0x8e) AUXR;
```

Comment: Thanks, those details always make the difference

Comment: If you think the answer fits, please don't post "thank you" comments. ;-) Mark the answer instead. -- You might like to freshen up your knowledge how to use StackOverflow...